# Difference between past, past perfect, past perfect progressive tenses

Tags: difference, sentence-usage

I am wondering what is the difference, and in what case should I use these sentences:

- "I walked a lot to get there"
- "I have walked a lot to get there"
- "I have been walking a lot to get there"

Comment: There's plenty of resources explaining English tenses... see, for example: http://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/tenses , http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/verbtenseintro.html , http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/tenses/tense_frames.htm , or http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another

Answer (score 1):

> I walked a lot to get there - The *walking* happened in past with no period/time specified. 
>   I have walked a lot to get there - Suggests that you have recently walked **or** at least the effect of the sentence is still remaining while you spoke that. 
>   I have been walking a lot to get there - Suggests the continuous process of your efforts of walking.

Let me try some examples building context -

**I walked a lot to get there**

> *"Hey, do you know where is a good restaurant in 'X' area, the outskirts of New Delhi? I'm going there next week* ~ *"Yeah, I do as I've been there. It's at 'Y' place but a bit far. And trust me, **I walked a lot to get there."***

**I have walked a lot to get there.**

> *"No son, I cannot play with you now. I am just back from 'X' place and my legs are terribly paining. Trust me, **I have walked a lot to get there.***

**I have been walking a lot to get there.**

> *"[On phone] Harry, it seems the location you sent is not correct. My other friend told me that it's nearer but taking your route, *it seems* that **I've been walking a lot to get there.** Are you sure about the route you sent?*